# Convert PHP Array to HTML Breadcrumbs

Tags: php, html, arrays, breadcrumbs

I want to convert the following php array:

```
$crumbs = array(
'Financial Accounting'  => 'financial',
'Ratio Analysis'        => 'ratios',
'Current Ratio'         => 'current-ratio'
);
```

to html breadcrumb as shown below:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/financial/">Financial Accounting</a></li>
  <li><a href="/financial/ratios/">Ratios Analysis</a></li>
  <li><a href="/financial/ratios/current-ratio">Current Ratio</a></li>
</ul>
```

Anyone please show me how to do it in php. Thanks !!

**UPDATE:** Thanks for your help. Following is what worked for me:

```
<?php
$dotname = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$crumbs = array(
'Financial Accounting'  => 'financial',
'Ratio Analysis'        => 'ratios',
'Current Ratio'         => 'current-ratio'
);
echo("<ul>\n<li><a href=\"/\">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;</li>\n");
foreach ($crumbs as $atext => $aloc) {
    if ($dotname != 'index.php' && $aloc == end($crumbs)) {
        $url .= '/'.$aloc;
        echo("<li><a href=\"$url\">$atext</a></li>\n");
    } else {
        $url .= '/'.$aloc;
        echo("<li><a href=\"$url/\">$atext</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;</li>\n");
    }
}
echo('</ul>');
?>
```

Comment: This isn't "how to solve a problem" but "show me codez" type of question. All I can say is that you'll need foreach and a temporary string which will contain previous breadcrumbs.

Comment: What have you tried already?  Please post your existing code, even if it is broken.  Let us know which particular part you're getting stuck on and we'll help you fix that.

Comment: And it looks like another kid gets away with letting someone else do their homework for them.  For free no less...

Comment: Seems you need to learn coding first. Did you even try any thing? if yes, show the code. May be we can fix it.

Comment: It's kinda funny. There are 5 answers and only one got it right. :D Score-hunters! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with a foreach and a variable to remember the path. I'll whip up an example in a few seconds.

> **[A Working Can be Found Here!](http://codepad.org/fkKzWBdG)**

Comment: Please don't, let him struggle with that.

Comment: Your solution helped me a lot. Thank you so much. I modified it a little bit to suit my site structure because it does not have trailing slashes in deep pages.

Comment: Sure thing. Make sure to read the manual next time, and maybe consider taking a few lessons. What you asked is a very basic string manipulation. @erfan

Answer (score 1):

Somthing like that?:

```
<ul>
<?php
foreach($crumb as $name=>$href){
   echo "<a href=/'$href'>$name</a>"; 
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<?php
$path = '/';
foreach($crumbs as $name => $href) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$path.$href.'/"></li>';
    $path .= $name.'/';
}
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
<?php
function ConvertPHPArrayToBreadcrumb($arr) {
    //convert the php array to html breadcrumb as required in 
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464019/convert-php-array-to-html-breadcrumbs
    $crmbs = '<ul> <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>';
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        $crmbs .= '<li><a href="' . $val . '/">' . $key . '</a></li>';
    }
    $crmbs .= "</ul>";
    return $crmbs;
}


//define the array
$crumbs = array(
    'Financial Accounting' => 'financial',
    'Ratio Analysis' => 'ratios',
    'Current Ratio' => 'current-ratio'
);

//call the convert function
$html_crumbs = ConvertPHPArrayToBreadcrumb($crumbs);

//echo the reuls
echo($html_crumbs);
?>
```

Comment: Your function names change halfway through.

Comment: ..and it doesn't do what he wants. But nevermind, don't show him teh codez.

Answer (score 0):

```
function showcrumbs($crumbs) {
    echo '<ul><li><a href="/">Home</a></li>';
    $path='/';
        foreach($crumbs as $name=>$href){
            echo '<li><a href="'.$path.$href.'">'.$name.'</a></li>'; 
            $path = $path.$href.'/';
        }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Usage:

```
<?php
function showcrumbs($crumbs) {
    echo '<ul><li><a href="/">Home</a></li>';
    $path='/';
        foreach($crumbs as $name=>$href){
            echo '<li><a href="'.$path.$href.'">'.$name.'</a></li>'; 
            $path = $path.$href.'/';
        }
    echo '</ul>';
}
$crumbs = array(
'Financial Accounting'  => 'financial',
'Ratio Analysis'        => 'ratios',
'Current Ratio'         => 'current-ratio'
);
showcrumbs($crumbs);
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't do what he want.

Comment: The urls have to be nested in each iteration. p.s. the only one who got it right is @haynar.

Comment: This outputs exactly what his example asked for?